# Microservices with Spring Boot, Netflix, Docker, Maven. How to organize development?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, microservices, netflix

I'm new to Microservices and I chose the following stack as an exercise.

1. I want to build some apis with Spring boot, Netflix apis and Maven
2. Dockerize the microservices so that I can deploy in Cloud Foundry but also on Kubernetes or AWS
3. Build a PWA with a javascript framework and call those APIs

A bit ambitious..

I get that microservices will be deployed separately. I get that web app will connect to the gateway first, etc..

But as a new developer who starts to work in a team who's developing a search-product api for example, will I open my STS, clone the only repository will the microservices projects (including gateway, registry, config server) OR will I clone the repository which contain the spring boot project I need to work on? In the first case it seems it make sense to have a parent pom project with modules and maybe share some jars.. dunno..

I think I might have found part of the answer I was looking for 
[Microservices: How to store source code of many microservices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286443/microservices-how-to-store-source-code-of-many-microservices)

Comment: too broad a question

Comment: Mainly it would be good to know if I should use multi-module project which means sharing the service-registry, config-server and gateway or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions are amazingly broad.  I think first you should do a bit of reading...

1. Domain driven design by eric evans
2. Building microservices by sam newman

Next you should understand a bit of architectural design patterns.
Check out event sourceing, CQRS, APi gateways, Service registration, and general cloud patterns. This list could go siginificantly longer but it's a good start.

Then basically your api gateway should be where all the frontend calls come to and go through security, monitoring, and routeing.

The api gateway will contact the service registry which is eureka and get the location information of the service your routeing to.

All your service applications will register with eureka and pull there configurations from the config server.

If you are building this as a production application you will most likely have all these applications in different repositories.  To facilitate all the pieces of an architectural stack most larger companies will have regulatory and business guidance which means separate teams of people will handle each piece in some cases or they will handle vertical slices in other organizations.  If you were in a startup environment you might be asked to handle the full architecture.

Imagine for a second that you are a single employee at a company that has potentially hundreds of internal API's would you build all the services and manage the monitoring, routing, and security at the API gateway probably not.

I think that if you are simply just learning the patterns and the implementations, that putting it in a single project is much simpler for you as a single developer.

These are my thoughts on that.  You can easily find tutorials to explain how to build these patterns and applications but they normally just show you how to get started.  I would suggest if you are doing this to learn that you pick some fun(fake) business idea and start building/learning!

Hopefully this is helpful good luck!

PS: check out sleuth and zipkin for distributed tracing

Comment: Thanks. I've already had a look at the book of Eric Evans but I'll definitely check the other one. You also seem to confirm to have separate microservices, but you said there will be a gateway, a config server and a server registry. Considering I want to use Spring boot to build all of this, how do I actually implement it?

Comment: @Gfalco you can search github.com to find many examples of spring cloud features being used.  I have one as well which you can take a look at.  It's a working example so many features I intend are not there yet and may not get added based on my ambition. https://github.com/Matt-st/CoffeeShop

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for sharing but now I'm a bit confused. Your example is very similar of what I have done, see https://github.com/gfalco77/ecommerce-microservices. I haven't created the pom.xml with the modules though. If we have separate teams that build different microservices and therefore different repositories, how is it going to work?

Comment: It should not matter where the code is stored at...it should simply be about where they are deployed at.  I am not sure I understand the question can you maybe give an example or better articulate the question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A more practical answer to your question

**Project structure:**

A *multi-module* project works best for microservices that are highly coupled. Meaning: are gonna be used exclusively among themselves and pretty much look to the rest of the infrastructure as a single service.

In the real world, you use a microservice architecture so most -if not all- applications can benefit from any microservice present in your infrastructure. Think about it as a network where each node is an application that exposes a service. I'd suggest having one independent spring boot project per microservice.

**Dockerizing microservices:**

The easiest/simplest way to achieve it is to:

1. **Package your spring boot project:** Using maven (maven goal package). This is gonna create an executable jar file.
2. **Create a Dockerfile:** that contains and runs your jar file. Something like:

```
FROM jdk:latest
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /srv
COPY ms.jar .
CMD java -jar ms.jar
```

3. **Create a docker image:** `docker build -t ms:latest path/to/Dockerfile`

Take into consideration that for production, you might need to add multiple instances of your app, use a more powerful app server or adjust JVM initialization parameters. This is just a basic procedure for you to start with something.

I'll leave it until here cause your question is related to how to structure your project and how to use maven to package your spring boot app into a docker image.

Comment: Thanks, you answered one of my question. The other one is, are those 3 projects (service-registry, gateway, config server) shared between the microservices or not? For example, could I package them in a jar and imported them into each pom for each microservice?

Comment: @Gfalco They would be shared between the microservices.

Comment: @Gflaco Gotcha, microservices are standalone apps that communicate each other via their exposed endpoints. Rather than having a dependency/lib in your projects, you develop requests to the other services/apps. App1 can send a request to App2, which is gonna send back a response that App1 is able to parse and interpret so it can do _something_ with it.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying to Cloud Foundry, there is no need to "Dockerize" as the Cloud Foundry container already manages that. Same for AWS. I believe both of those platforms allow you to manage your own container though, if you really want to torture yourself. As far as the whole project goes, I recommend starting small and expanding the scope incrementally. This will help keep you from becoming overwhelmed and giving up. Start with a small deliverable, and develop an implementation plan that you can track in a backlog that eventually reaches your final design goal. I am sure you will see your original idea incrementally change as you work through the backlog.

Comment: Thanks. I know but I need to learn Docker. About the backlog, that's exactly what I wanted to do.